# Are there works in progress to create Python > 2.4 support for Pythonnator in Apache UIMA C++ framework?

Tags: python, spacy, uima

**Segmentation fault while running Python 2.4 program against SpaCy-based program (Python 2.7)**

I am running a **Python 2.4** program (Pythonnator) which should interact with a **Python 2.7** program (SciSpacy, which is based on SpaCy). The reason I am doing this [i.e., Python 2.4 <--> Python 2.7] is because both Pythonnator and SpaCy/SciSpacy don't seem to be compatible with each other out-of-the-box.

When I try that, I get a segmentation fault error. Any help on how to address this version mimatch?

```
Pythonnator: Initialize - debug=101
Pythonnator: Registered function initialize
Pythonnator: no function registered for typeSystemInit
Pythonnator: no function registered for destroy
Pythonnator: no function registered for reconfigure
Pythonnator: Registered function process
Pythonnator: no function registered for batchProcessComplete
Pythonnator: no function registered for collectionProcessComplete
Reading data
Pythonnator: typeSystemInit

ThreadId: 140188654634880 runAECpp: Processing started. Number of runs 1 rdelay 0 millis. 

ThreadId: 140188654634880 runAECpp::processing start iteration: 0

ThreadId: 140188654634880 runAECpp::processing example.txt 
Pythonnator: process 
process method
loading model..
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to ask about plans of external projects. But generally speaking both 2.4 and 2.7 are outdated Python versions. Don't rely on software not supporting Puthon 3 anymore.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question should be directed to the project itself.

Answer (score 0):

You might care to have a look at the **rc/uimacpp-3.0.0** branch of UIMACPP - the project which includes the Pythonnator:

https://github.com/apache/uima-uimacpp/tree/rc/uimacpp-3.0.0

It claims to support Python 2.7

https://github.com/apache/uima-uimacpp/blob/rc/uimacpp-3.0.0/scriptators/python/Python.html